# how to filter the listview by using onOptionsItemSelected method in android?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am developing an android application ,In that i have 3 tabs namely,

```
             1.Invitation tab(it have the invitation listviews) 
             2.Event tab(it have the event listviewes)
             3.Groupchat tab(it have both invitation and event listviewes)
```

I have a dropdown(that present on dashboard layout) in gropchat tab that have 3 items namely(All,Event,Invitation).Now my need is,I want to filter my Listviews in Groupchat tab based on Dropdown item click functionality(for example,when on tap "Event" item i need to display only the event listviewes).How can i achieve this,Please help me.

My programming code is below,

```
public class GroupChatFragment extends Fragment {


    private Context context;
    private ListView chatListView;
    private TextView chatTitle;
    private TextView chatPlace;
    private TextView chatDate;
    private String dateResult;
    private List<EventMO> groupEventMoList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EventMO> eventMOs = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<EventMO> invitationMOs = new ArrayList<>();
    private EventDelegates eventDelegates = new EventDelegates();
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private ProgressDialog prgDialog;
    private ChatDisplayAdapter chatDisplayAdapter;
    private ListView GroupEventView;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private TextView eventList;
    private MessageMO messageMO = new MessageMO();

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.all:

                return true;
            case R.id.event:

                return true;
            case R.id.invitation:

                return true;

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void Event() {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
        }.getType());
        List<EventMO> groupEventMOList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
            groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow_tab, container, false);
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        prgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        prgDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        // Set Cancelable as False
        prgDialog.setCancelable(false);
        prgDialog.show();
        //inviation group for user
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                invitationMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventForUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                List<EventMO> groupEventMOList = new ArrayList<>();

                for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                    groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);

                }
                for (EventMO eventMO : invitationMOs) {
                    groupEventMOList.add(eventMO);

                }
                return groupEventMOList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventMOList) {
                groupEventMoList = groupEventMOList;
                prgDialog.dismiss();
                DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
                //long totalInsertion = dbHelper.insertUserRelationTable(userMOs);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "total userMos size " + userMOs.size() + "total db insertion size " + totalInsertion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                GroupEventView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.chat_list_view);
                chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                GroupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                GroupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                GroupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                GroupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(GroupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
            }
        }.execute(null, null, null);
        return view;
    }


    private class ChatDisplayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ChatDisplayAdapter() {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return groupEventMoList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return groupEventMoList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int id) {
            // for sqllite management
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.chatwindow, null);
                convertView.setClickable(true);
                convertView.setFocusable(true);

                chatTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_title);
                chatPlace = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_place);
                chatDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
                chatPlace.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                chatDate.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                chatTitle.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                chatPlace.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getPlace());
                String actualDate = groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate();
                //chatDate.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getEventDate());
                try {
                    //date format changed here
                    Date formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(actualDate);
                    dateResult = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(formatDate);
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                chatDate.setText(dateResult);
                chatTitle.setText(groupEventMoList.get(position).getText());
                convertView.setTag(position);
                View v = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chat_window_single);
                v.getRootView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.i("position", v.getTag().toString());
                        Intent groupAct = new Intent(context, GroupChatActivity.class);
                        groupAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        groupAct.putExtra("eventMo", groupEventMoList.get(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())));
                        startActivity(groupAct);
                    }

                });
            }
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write custom adapter for each Spinner selection, you need to give a category to each one then set data/values of selected categories to the Listview.

Comment: can you please suggest me the code..because i am fresher in android application development.

Comment: you should search for "binding Spinner with listview" and adding custom arrayadapter